# Android ViewPager with tabs save state

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager

I'm implementing a `ViewPager` with tabs similar to implementation provided by Google [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html).

My app has the following behaviour. My `ViewPager` has 3 "pages" (fragA, fragB, fragC) and I'm implementing 3 tabs on top of the `ViewPager`. The differece between google's implementation and mine is that the tabs aren't used to navigate between `fragments`.
As an example, pressing one of my tabs, loads a different set of data on the visible fragment. I can have `fragA` with `tab3` selected, `fragB` with `tab2` selected and `fragC`with `tab1` selected.

When I swipe between the fragments I want to maintain the state that is, the tab that is currently selected.
I'm achiving this with this code:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && mTabHost != null) {
        if (mTabHost.getCurrentTab() != selectedTimePeriod) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(selectedTimePeriod);
        }
    }
}
```

I have the above code in the 3 fragments and this is working as expected almost every time but unfortunatly in some situation, that i can't even exactly reproduce since it happens randonly, the state isn't maintained.

Whats the proper way to save the state of my tabs (for example between screen rotation) between `Viewpager` swipes?

Comment: have you tried setOnPageChangeListener of ViewPager

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
viepagerObj.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)
```

This will load fragments and keep it in memory. For example in you case at the time of launch apart from the first one(fragC) the next 2 fragments(fragB and fragA) will be loaded and saves in memory. By default the value is 1, means frag C + the next fragment(fragB) is loaded and when you swipe right fragA will load removing fragC and vice versa.

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately that does not solve my problem. When rotating screen I cant maintain the correct tab selected

Comment: did you tried  setRetainInstance(true); inside fragment for retaining state while orientation changes

Comment: Also if you dont want to load UI during orientation change you can use  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" for the activity in manifest file

Comment: you are saying that while swiping the state is not retained. I guess that issue is solved by using setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

Comment: Hi. `setRetainInstance(true);` does not work and `setOffscreenPageLimit(2);` has the same behaviour